# Ocultar/Mostrar campo Kartik Select2

Tags: php, yii2

Buen día, no he podido realizar algo que al parecer es sencillo. Se trata de ocultar campos acorde a opción elegida por el usuario.
Tengo 3 campos: 1- Pago? 2- Medio de pago 3- Numero de pago o transacción todos con kartik select2.
Necesito que al elegir la opción 1(si) en 1- Pago?, me active Medio de pago, si es 2(no), me oculte el campo 2-medio de pago.
Si el campo 1-Pago? es 1(si), y el campo 2- Medio de pago, es cualquiera de estas opciones (1,3,4,5,6,8) Muestre el campo 3- Numero de pago o transacción y sea obligatorio. si es una de las opciones 2 y 7, permanezca oculto el campo 3- Numero de pago o transacción.

[image: Campos]

[image: Opciones SI - NO en 1- Pago si o no?]

[image: Si en 1- Pago si o no? es 1(Si) active 2- Medio de pago y se pueda elegir opción]

[image: Si campo 1 es 1(si) y campo 2 es una de las opciones 1,3,4,5,6,8 diligenciar el campo obligatorio]

en el form de la vista:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use kartik\datecontrol\DateControl;
use app\models\Pagosp;
use app\models\Mediopago;
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Pedidos */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>
<div class="pedidos-form">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'dynamic-form', 'options'=>['style'=>'width:750px;margin:0px auto;']]); ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, "PagoId")->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                    'language'=>'en',
                    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Pagosp::find()->all(), 'Id','Nombre'), 'options'=>['placeholder'=>'Elija SI pagó o NO', 'Nombre'=>'PagoId'],
                    'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear'=>true],
                ]); ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, "MedipagoId")->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                    'language'=>'en',
                    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Mediopago::find()->all(), 'Id','Nombre'), 'options'=>['placeholder'=>'Elija medio de pago', 'Nombre'=>'MedipagoId'],
                    'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear'=>true],
                ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, "IdPago")->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder'=>'Coloque Número de Autorización, sólo si el cliente pago con tarjetas o giro']) ?>            


         <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Guardar'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

En el controlador:

```
/**
 * PedidosController implements the CRUD actions for Pedidos model.
 */
class PedidosController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Pedidos models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new PedidosSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);


        if (Yii::$app->request->post('hasEditable')) 
            {
                $Id = Yii::$app->request->post('editableKey');
                $searchModel = Pedidos::findOne($Id);

                $out = Json::encode(['output' =>'','message'=>'']);
                $post=[];
                $posted = current($_POST['Pedidos']);
                $post['Pedidos'] = $posted;

                if ($searchModel->load($post))
                {
                    $searchModel->save();
                    $output = '';
                    $out = Json::encode(['output' =>'DATO ACTUALIZADO','message'=>'']);
                }

                echo $out;
                return;
            }











        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Pedidos model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $modelo = $this->findModel($id);
        $searchModel = new PedidoProducto();
        $searchModel->pedido_id = $modelo->Id;
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->searchProductos(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $modelo->Id);

        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $modelo,
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Pedidos model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Pedidos;
        $productos = [new PedidoProducto];

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $productos = Pedidos::createMultiple(PedidoProducto::classname());
            Model::loadMultiple($productos, Yii::$app->request->post());

            // ajax validation
            /*if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
                Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
                return ActiveForm::validateMultiple($productos);
            }*/

            $valido = $model->validate();
            $valido = Model::validateMultiple($productos) && $valido;

            if ($valido) {
                $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
                try {
                    $totalProducto = 0;
                    if($model->save())
                    {
                        foreach ($productos as $k=>$producto)
                        {
                            $mPro = $producto->producto;

                            //Calcular total producto
                            $valorProducto = ($producto->cantidad * $mPro->ProductosPrecioVenta);
                            $totalProducto = ($totalProducto + $valorProducto);

                            $producto->pedido_id = $model->Id;
                            $producto->valor_unitario = $mPro->ProductosPrecioVenta;
                            $producto->valor_total = $valorProducto;
                            $producto->fecha_registro = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                            $producto->save();

                            //Actualizar el stock del producto
                            //Productos::actualizarStockProducto($model->ProductosId);
                            $mPro->actualizarStockProducto();
                        }
                    }

                    if($model->Id <> '')
                    {
                        //Calcular total pedido;
                        $totalPedido = ($totalProducto + $model->Valorenvio);

                        //Actualizar total producto y total pedido
                        $model->TotalProducto = $totalProducto;
                        $model->TotalPedido = $totalPedido;
                        $model->save();

                        $transaction->commit();
                        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->Id]);
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $transaction->rollBack();
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'productos' => (empty($productos)) ? [new PedidoProducto] : $productos,
        ]);
    }

    public function actionCreate_old()
    {
        $model = new Pedidos();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $producto = $model->productos;

            //Calcular total producto
            $totalProducto = $model->Cantidad * $producto->ProductosPrecioVenta;

            //Calcular total pedido;
            $totalPedido = $totalProducto + $model->Valorenvio;

            $model->TotalProducto = $totalProducto;
            $model->TotalPedido = $totalPedido;
            $model->save();

            //Actualizar el stock del producto
            //Productos::actualizarStockProducto($model->ProductosId);
            $producto->actualizarStockProducto();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->Id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'productos' => false,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Pedidos model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $productos = $model->pedidoProductos;

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $oldIDs = ArrayHelper::map($productos, 'id', 'id');
            $productos = Pedidos::createMultiple(PedidoProducto::classname(), $productos);
            Model::loadMultiple($productos, Yii::$app->request->post());
            $deletedIDs = array_diff($oldIDs, array_filter(ArrayHelper::map($productos, 'id', 'id')));

            // ajax validation
            /*if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
                Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
                return ActiveForm::validateMultiple($productos);
            }*/

            $valido = $model->validate();
            $valido = Model::validateMultiple($productos) && $valido;

            if ($valido) {
                $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
                try {
                    if($model->save())
                    {
                        if (! empty($deletedIDs)) {
                            PedidoProducto::deleteAll(['id' => $deletedIDs]);
                        }

                        $totalProducto = 0;
                        foreach ($productos as $k=>$producto)
                        {
                            $mPro = $producto->producto;

                            //Calcular total producto
                            $valorProducto = ($producto->cantidad * $mPro->ProductosPrecioVenta);
                            $totalProducto = ($totalProducto + $valorProducto);

                            $producto->pedido_id = $model->Id;
                            $producto->valor_unitario = $mPro->ProductosPrecioVenta;
                            $producto->valor_total = $valorProducto;
                            if($producto->id == '')
                            {
                                $producto->fecha_registro = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                            }
                            $producto->save();

                            //Actualizar el stock del producto
                            //Productos::actualizarStockProducto($model->ProductosId);
                            $mPro->actualizarStockProducto();
                        }

                        //Calcular total pedido;
                        $totalPedido = ($totalProducto + $model->Valorenvio);

                        //Actualizar total producto y total pedido
                        $model->TotalProducto = $totalProducto;
                        $model->TotalPedido = $totalPedido;
                        $model->save();
                    }

                    if($model->Id <> '')
                    {
                        $transaction->commit();
                        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->Id]);
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $transaction->rollBack();
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
            'productos' => (empty($productos)) ? [new PedidoProducto] : $productos,
        ]);
    }

    public function actionUpdate_old($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $producto = $model->productos;

            //Calcular total producto
            $totalProducto = $model->Cantidad * $producto->ProductosPrecioVenta;

            //Calcular total pedido;
            $totalPedido = $totalProducto + $model->Valorenvio;

            $model->TotalProducto = $totalProducto;
            $model->TotalPedido = $totalPedido;
            $model->save();

            //Actualizar el stock del producto
            //Productos::actualizarStockProducto($model->ProductosId);
            $producto->actualizarStockProducto();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->Id]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
            'productos' => false,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Pedidos model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $productos = $model->pedidoProductos;
        if($productos)
        {
            foreach($productos as $pr)
            {
                $producto = $pr->producto;
                $pr->delete();
                $producto->actualizarStockProducto();
            }

        }
        $model->delete();




        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Pedidos model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Pedidos the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Pedidos::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not exist.'));
    }
}
```

En el modelo:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;


class Pedidos extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'pedidos';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['PagoId'], 'required', 'message' => 'Debe especificar si pagó o no'],
      //  [['MedipagoId'], 'required', 'message' => 'Debe elegir un medio de pago'],
        [['MedipagoId'], 'required', 'message' => 'Debe elegir un medio de pago', 'whenClient' => "function(attribute, value) { return $('#metodoPago').is(':visible'); }"],
        [['IdPago'], 'required', 'message' => 'Cliente pagó con tarjeta, digite Número de Autorización', 'whenClient' => "function(attribute, value) { return $('#idPago').is(':visible'); }"],
        [['MedipagoId', 'PagoId'], 'integer'],
        [['IdPago'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['MedipagoId'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Mediopago::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['MedipagoId' => 'Id']],
        [['PagoId'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Pagosp::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['PagoId' => 'Id']],
    ];
}
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [

            'PagoId' => Yii::t('app', 'Pagó?'),

            'MedipagoId' => Yii::t('app', 'Medio de Pago'),


            'IdPago' => Yii::t('app', 'Num. Pago o Transacción'),

            'medipago.Nombre' => Yii::t('app', 'Medio de pago'),

        ];
    }



    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getPedidoProductos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PedidoProducto::className(), ['pedido_id' => 'Id']);
    }
    public function getPagosped()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Pagosp::className(), ['Id' => 'PagoId']);
    }



    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getMedipago()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Mediopago::className(), ['Id' => 'MedipagoId']);
    }









    /**
     * Creates and populates a set of models.
     *
     * @param string $modelClass
     * @param array $multipleModels
     * @return array
     */
    public static function createMultiple($modelClass, $multipleModels = [])
    {
        $model    = new $modelClass;
        $formName = $model->formName();
        $post     = Yii::$app->request->post($formName);
        $models   = [];

        if (! empty($multipleModels)) {
            $keys = array_keys(ArrayHelper::map($multipleModels, 'id', 'id'));
            $multipleModels = array_combine($keys, $multipleModels);
        }

        if ($post && is_array($post)) {
            foreach ($post as $i => $item) {
                if (isset($item['id']) && !empty($item['id']) && isset($multipleModels[$item['id']])) {
                    $models[] = $multipleModels[$item['id']];
                } else {
                    $models[] = new $modelClass;
                }
            }
        }

        unset($model, $formName, $post);

        return $models;
    }
}
```

EN LA VISTA CORREGIDO:
CODIGO CORREGIDO: AHORA LA VALIDACION NO SIRVE COMO ESTÁ:

field($model, "PagoId")->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'language'=>'en',
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Pagosp::find()->all(), 'Id','Nombre'), 'options'=>['placeholder'=>'Elija SI pagó o NO', 'Nombre'=>'PagoId'],
        'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear'=>true],
        'pluginEvents' => [
            'change' => 'function() { 
                    if($(this).val() == 1){
                        $("#metodoPago").show() 
                    } else {
                    $("#metodoPago").hide() 
                    $("#idPago").hide() 
                }}'
        ]     
    ]); ?>

    
        field($model, "MedipagoId")->widget(Select2::classname(), [
            'language'=>'en',
            'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Mediopago::find()->all(), 'Id','Nombre'), 'options'=>['placeholder'=>'Elija medio de pago', 'Nombre'=>'MedipagoId'],
            'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear'=>true],
            'pluginEvents' => [
                'change' => 'function() { 
                if($.inArray($(this).val(), [1,3,4,5,6,8])){

                    if($(this).val() == 1){
                        $("#idPago").show()
                    } 
                    else if($(this).val() == 2){
                        $("#idPago").hide() 
                    }
                    else if($(this).val() == 3){
                       $("#idPago").show() 
                    }
                    else if($(this).val() == 4){
                       $("#idPago").show() 
                    }
                    else if($(this).val() == 5){
                       $("#idPago").show() 
                    }
                    else if($(this).val() == 6){
                       $("#idPago").show() 
                    }
                    else if($(this).val() == 8){
                       $("#idPago").show() 
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#idPago").hide() 
                    }
                }}'
            ]    
        ]); ?>
    
    
        field($model, "IdPago")->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder'=>'Coloque Número de Autorización, sólo si el cliente pago con tarjetas o giro']) ?>            
    
 
         'btn btn-success']) ?>

[image: Desoculta información y no hace validación correcta]

ESTRUCTURA PEDIDOS:
#

## Structure for table "pedidos"

#

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pedidos`;
CREATE TABLE `pedidos` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `RemitoNro` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT '0',
  `Fecha` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ClienteId` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `VendedoresId` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `MedipagoId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CanalventaId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `apodo` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Calificacion` char(60) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Idcompra` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `IdPago` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `AgenciaId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FechaEntrega` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Lugarentrega` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `TotalProducto` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `TotalPedido` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `Valorenvio` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `Observaciones` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EstadoId` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `TotalPedido2` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `PagoId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TotalProducto2` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `Puntos` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `ClienteId` (`ClienteId`),
  KEY `VendedoresId` (`VendedoresId`),
  KEY `MedipagoId` (`MedipagoId`),
  KEY `CanalventaId` (`CanalventaId`),
  KEY `AgenciaId` (`AgenciaId`),
  KEY `ProductosId` (`ProductosId`),
  KEY `ImpuestosId` (`ImpuestosId`),
  KEY `EstadoId` (`EstadoId`),
  KEY `Pago` (`PagoId`),
  CONSTRAINT `pedidos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ClienteId`) REFERENCES `clientes` (`Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `pedidos_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`VendedoresId`) REFERENCES `vendedores` (`Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `pedidos_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`MedipagoId`) REFERENCES `mediopago` (`Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `pedidos_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`CanalventaId`) REFERENCES `canales` (`Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `pedidos_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`AgenciaId`) REFERENCES `agencias` (`Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `pedidos_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`ProductosId`) REFERENCES `productos` (`ProductosId`),
  CONSTRAINT `pedidos_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`ImpuestosId`) REFERENCES `impuestos` (`Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `pedidos_ibfk_8` FOREIGN KEY (`EstadoId`) REFERENCES `estadosp` (`Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `pedidos_ibfk_9` FOREIGN KEY (`PagoId`) REFERENCES `pagosp` (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_spanish_ci;

---

Y DE ESTA TABLA SACO LA INFORMACION DE PRODUCTOS ASOCIADOS.
#

## Structure for table "pedido_producto"

#

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pedido_producto`;
CREATE TABLE `pedido_producto` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pedido_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `producto_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cantidad` float NOT NULL,
  `valor_unitario` float NOT NULL,
  `valor_total` float NOT NULL,
  `valor_condescuento` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_registro` datetime NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `pedido_id` (`pedido_id`),
  KEY `pedido_producto_idx` (`producto_id`,`pedido_id`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `pedido_producto_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`pedido_id`) REFERENCES `pedidos` (`Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `pedido_producto_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`producto_id`) REFERENCES `productos` (`ProductosId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_spanish_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

EN EL _FORM, LUEGO DE LOS CAMPOS IDPAGO, MEDIPAGOID, E IDPAGO TENGO LO SIGUIENTE:

'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
        'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
        'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
        'limit' => 30, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
        'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
        'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
        'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
        'model' => $productos[0],
        'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
        'formFields' => [
            'producto_id',
            'cantidad',
        ],
    ]);

    ?>

---

Agregar producto
    
     $producto): ?>
        
            
                Producto: 1
                Eliminar
                
            
            

                isNewRecord) {
                        echo Html::activeHiddenInput($producto, "[{$i}]id");
                    }
                ?

    field($producto, "[{$i}]producto_id", [
                    'template' => '{label}{input}{error}{hint}',
                ])->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                    'language'=>'en',
                    'data' => [],
                    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Productos::find()->asArray()->all(), 'ProductosId',
                    function($model) {
                                      return $model['ProductosCodigo'].'  /  '.$model['ProductosNombre'].'  /   Precio:  $'.$model['ProductosPrecioVenta'].' / '.'Existencias:'.'  '.$model['ProductoStock'];
                    }   
                ),
                    'options'=>['placeholder'=>'Elija un Producto', 'ProductosNombre'=>'ProductosId'], 
        'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear'=>true],

        ]);
    ?>                      
    field($producto, "[{$i}]cantidad", [
        'template' => '{label}#{input}{error}{hint}',
            ])->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'form-control cantidades_producto']);
    ?>
        
    
    
    
     Agregar producto
    
    
         'btn btn-success']) ?>

.glyphicon{
        top: 0px;
    }
    .btn-add-item
    {
        top: -30px;
        position: relative;
    }

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente agrega el `pluginEvents` a tu select y envuelve el dato que quieres mostrar/no mostrar en un div, para una manera más fácil de localizarlo

tu vista quedaría así

```
 <div class="pedidos-form">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'dynamic-form', 'options'=>['style'=>'width:750px;margin:0px auto;']]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, "PagoId")->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'language'=>'en',
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Pagosp::find()->all(), 'Id','Nombre'), 'options'=>['placeholder'=>'Elija SI pagó o NO', 'Nombre'=>'PagoId'],
        'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear'=>true],
        'pluginEvents' => [
            'change' => 'function() { 
                if($.inArray($(this).val(), [1,3,4,5,6,8])){
                    $("#metodoPago").show() 
                } else {
                $("#metodoPago").hide() 
            }'
        ]     
    ]); ?>

    <div> id="metodoPago">
        <?= $form->field($model, "MedipagoId")->widget(Select2::classname(), [
            'language'=>'en',
            'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Mediopago::find()->all(), 'Id','Nombre'), 'options'=>['placeholder'=>'Elija medio de pago', 'Nombre'=>'MedipagoId'],
            'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear'=>true],
            'pluginEvents' => [
                'change' => 'function() { 
                    if($(this).val() == 1){
                        $("#idPago").show() 
                    } else {
                    $("#idPago").hide() 
                }'
            ]    
        ]); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="idPago">
        <?= $form->field($model, "IdPago")->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder'=>'Coloque Número de Autorización, sólo si el cliente pago con tarjetas o giro']) ?>            
    </idPago>

         <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Guardar'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Para el método de pago en el rules puedes intentar con esto

```
 [['MedipagoId'], 'required', 'message' => 'Debe elegir un medio de pago', 'whenClient' => "function(attribute, value) { return $('#metodoPago').is(':visible'); }"]]
```

LO SOLUCIONÉ ASI:

['MedipagoId', 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
                                                        return $model->PagoId == 1;
                                                 }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
                                                                         return $(this).val() == 1;
                                                                    }"

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84690/discussion-on-answer-by-sr1871-ocultar-mostrar-campo-kartik-select2).